# What is the system environment and requirement was used to build asp.net core2 api for deploying with Ubuntu platform?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm going to build asp.net core2 Web API based on open source platform for providing the services for my clients who built by **React Native**(IOS, Android) and **Reactjs** (Webs) due to building this projects I need to get more suggestion from overall developers for using NuGet packages and another framework to avoid some inconvenient cause which will happen in futures. However, my projects environment was listed as below

Authentication Middleware and Services :

- Auth2.0
- JWT (Beaer)
- Swagger
- Facebook Authentication
- Google Authentication
- Twitter Authentication

Packages:

- Entity Framework Core 2
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
- Newtonsoft.Json

This project will be deployed to Linux (Ubunto17.04 or higher)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, what is the error?

Comment: I said I need the suggestion.
So we can not ask here for any suggestion right?